# Selecting consecutive values from a bootstrap sample in r with repeated values

Tags: r

I'm not exactly sure how to go about this in R. I've got a data set with 40 values, some of which repeat and I want to perform a small bootstrap on this dataset to find the mean of two or more consecutive values. For example, I randomly select a value from the dataset provided below, say the very first value is selected which is 0.2, so x1=0.2. How can I make sure that in the same for loop R is able to select the next value, x2, to be 0.2 as that is the second value in the dataset? Thus it would appear as x1=0.2 and x2=0.2.

I can't really think of a way for this to be done as it would need to be repeated for each iteration and since the `sample()` function selects any random value that makes it harder to pinpoint exactly which value it selected given there are repeated values.

I've provided a sample code that calculates the mean for 1 observation and I would like to get it to work for 2 consecutive observations. So then I can calculate the means individually and display them.

If anyone has any way to handle this I would appreciate it.
Thanks ahead of time.

```
x=c(0.20,0.20,0.21,0.21,0.21,0.20,0.19,0.18,0.16,0.10,
      0.02,-0.02,0.01,0.03,0.07,0.14,0.22,0.13,0.12,
      0.16,0.17,0.18,0.18,0.17,0.15,0.15,0.13,0.12,
      0.10,0.08,0.06,0.04,0.03,0.02,0.03,0.05,0.34,
      0.13,0.11,0.12)
B<- 500
result1<- numeric(B)
# result2<- numerib(B)
for (b in 1:B){
  x1<-sample(x=x,size =1, replace=TRUE)
#  x2<-
  result1[b]<-x1
#  result2[b]<-x2
}
mean1<- mean(result1)
# mean2<- mean(result2)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple approach could be:

```r
result <- matrix(nrow = B, ncol = 2)

for (b in 1:B){
  idx1 <- sample(seq_along(x), size = 1)
  idx2 <- idx1 %% length(x) + 1
  result[b, 1] <- x[idx1]
  result[b, 2] <- x[idx2]
}
```

storing the results in a matrix:

```r
> result
        [,1]  [,2]
  [1,]  0.21  0.21
  [2,]  0.12  0.20
  [3,]  0.21  0.21
  [4,]  0.10  0.02
  [5,]  0.10  0.02
  [6,]  0.21  0.20
  [7,]  0.02 -0.02
  [8,] -0.02  0.01
  [9,]  0.21  0.20
 [10,]  0.17  0.15
```

Comment: Thanks, Martin, I like this construction as it gets mean what I am looking for and it also constructs a matrix of the output values I can use for further analysis before taking the means. This can also be extended for more than just 2 means if needed.

Answer (score 2):

Sample the *indices* of x, then use this to subset `x` for `result1`. Use the sampled index + 1 to subset x for `result2`. However, you also need a wrap around so that if you sample the last member of x, you sample the first as well (as the "next" value)

```r
B <- 500

result1<- numeric(B)
result2 <- numeric(B)

for(i in 1:B) {
  j <- sample(seq_along(x), 1)
  if(j == 40) k <- 1 
  else k <- j + 1
  result1[i] <- x[j]
  result2[i] <- x[k]
}
mean(result1)
#> [1] 0.12618
mean(result2)
#> [1] 0.13034
```

Note also that since R is vectorized, you don't need a loop here at all. You could just do:

```r
result1 <- sample(seq_along(x), 500, replace = TRUE)
result2 <- result1 + 1
result2[result2 == 41] <- 1

mean(x[result1])
#> [1] 0.12568

mean(x[result2])
#> [1] 0.12596
```

<sup>Created on 2022-03-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thanks for the response Allan, I actually thought about what to do in the case of the last value and I have decided to just remove it as it will not have a large significance in the analysis. This is just a subset of a larger dataset so the odds of the last value being selected is roughly (1/2500)*(1/500).

Answer (score 0):

Could you work out all the possible consecutive means and then sample from that? How about:

```
library(RcppRoll)

x=c(0.20,0.20,0.21,0.21,0.21,0.20,0.19,0.18,0.16,0.10,
    0.02,-0.02,0.01,0.03,0.07,0.14,0.22,0.13,0.12,
    0.16,0.17,0.18,0.18,0.17,0.15,0.15,0.13,0.12,
    0.10,0.08,0.06,0.04,0.03,0.02,0.03,0.05,0.34,
    0.13,0.11,0.12)

rollmean  <- roll_mean(x,2)

r <- sample(rollmean, 500, replace= T)

hist(r)
```

Which gives you:

[image: Histogram of bootstrap of consecutive means]

Comment: Thanks for the response, Unfortunately for the scope of the project I am working on I need to be able to work with consecutive values as well as the means. IN this case, the consecutive values are more meaningful than the means.